# How to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)\left(P\left(X<x\right)-P\left(X>x\right)\right)dx =0$

Tags: probability, density-function, integral

For a continuous random variable X
 , intuition tells me that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)P\left(X<x\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}$$
 and more weakly that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)P\left(X<x\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}\left(x\right)P\left(X>x\right)dx$$
 However, I can't figure out a way to rigorously justify this. Using the fact that $$f_{X}\left(x\right)dx=dF_{X}\left(x\right)$$
 works, but I don't want to use that line of thinking because it doesn't match the intuitive reason I think this is true. Any ideas on how to manipulate the integrals to find the equalities?

Comment: The result is immediate upon substituting $y=P(X\lt x)$, whence $dy=f_X(x)dx$. You will then need to evaluate $\int_0^1 y dy$.

Comment: Your suggestion is the strategy I mentioned I did not want to use, as it does not correspond to intuition.  It works, of course.  What I'm curious about is whether there is a way to manipulate the right side of the equation to get the left side.  I'm think about things like switching around the integration limits, multiplying quantities by -1, etc.  My intuition gave me the answers because of informal reasoning based on the shapes of the functions.

Comment: It looks like we have different intuitions.  Regardless, the substitution method is rigorous.

Comment: It looks like my wording was unclear.  I had a rigorous way to get the answer (your way), but it doesn't correspond to my intuition.  It's just something I could mathematically justify.  The first equation I wrote seemed intuitively true because in it, we consider the probability of falling below a cutoff, for every cutoff, weighted by how likely the cutoff is.

Comment: It would be a useful intuition to develop: this substitution is known as the [Probability integral transform](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22probability+integral+transform%22).  It reduces many complex questions to ones about uniform distributions.  For instance, it is the point of departure for the study of [copulas](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula).

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(X<x)$ since $X$ is continuous.

Let $I:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)F(x)dx.$ Then integration by parts gives:

$$I=F(x)^2|_{-\infty}^\infty-I=1-0-I=1-I.$$

Rearranging for $I$ gives your result.

Comment: This is another successful strategy, but it also does not correspond to the informal reasoning about the shapes of the curves being integrated.

Comment: @Biomath: You're ultimately calculating $E[F(X)]$, which doesn't really have that much intuition. Notice that in the above integration, the $1/2$ is more of an artifact of probability measures having area 1. Where the area 2, the answer would be 1.

Comment: I didn't even notice I was calculating $E[F(X)]$. That helps a little.